# Laravel Eloquent Search Form Query (Multiple parameters in form)

Tags: php, forms, view, laravel-4, routes

I'm trying to query a DB in Laravel using Eloquent. When I click the submit button on my view my page is not going to the results page and I believe i'm not querying the database. I think there's an issue with my Controller handleIndex or my routes because i'm trying to render the query results onto the results page.

Any ideas?

Here's my Routes.php file:

```
//Bind route parameters.
Route::model('game', 'Game');

// Show pages.
 Route::get('/', 'GameController@index');
 Route::get('/results', 'GameController@results');
 Route::get('/profile/{$Game}', 'GameController@profile');
```

My GameController.php is as follows:

```
public function index()
    {
        //show view of homepage
        return View::make('index');
        }

    public function handleIndex()
    {   
        //Handle each query from index form submissions
        $Game = Game::query();

        if(Input::has('Industry_Type'))
        {
            $Game->where('Industry_Type', Input::get('Industry_Type'));
        }
        if(Input::has('Office_State'))
        {
            $Game->where('Office_State', Input::get('Office_State'));
        }
        if(Input::has('Local_Name'))
        {
            $Game->where('Local_Name', Input::get('Local_Name'));
        }

        return View::make('results');
        }

    public function results(Games $game)
    {
        //show search results from index form

        return View::make('results', compact('game'));
        }

    public function profile()
    {
        //show individual game proifile
        return View::make('profile');
        }

    }
```

Lastly, my views index.blade.php:

```
<div class='main_search_form'> 


    <!--<form action="login" method="get"> -->

        {{ Form::open(array('method' =>'GET')) }}
        <div>
            <div>Find a Game to Join. Love the Work you do.</div>
                <div>Get Started</div>
                <select id="jobclass">
                    <option id="jobclass" name="jobclass" value="" disabled selected>What Type of Work Do You Do?</option>
                    <option>Truck Driver</option>
                    <option>Web Developer</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>In</div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter State" name="">
            <div>
                <div>Search by Game</div>   
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name A Game" name="">
            </div>
        <div>   
            {{Form::submit('Find A Game', array('class' => 'btn')) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
      <!--  </form> -->
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What's wrong with your code**

1) `handleIndex()` function handles your form processing. However, nowhere do i see your code attempting to use that function.

2) `handleIndex()` function should have a route attached to it.

3) In your view, you opened your form `{{ Form::open(array('method' =>'GET')) }}` without providing a URL, so your form was sending data on the same page, i.e index.

4) Your view form's inputs doesn't have a name. Give them one, else their values won't be submitted.

**How to make it right**

*Routes.php*

```
// Show pages.
Route::get('/', 'GameController@index');
Route::get('/results', 'GameController@results');
Route::get('/profile/{$Game}', 'GameController@profile');
//Form route handler
Route::get('/handle-index','GameController@handleIndex');
```

*View index.blade.php*

```
<div class='main_search_form'> 
    <!--<form action="login" method="get"> -->
    <!-- Added url parameter to form open -->
    {{ Form::open(array('method' =>'GET','url'=>'/handle-index')) }}
    <div>
        <div>Find a Game to Join. Love the Work you do.</div>
            <div>Get Started</div>
            <select id="jobclass">
                <option id="jobclass" name="jobclass" value="" disabled selected>What Type of Work Do You Do?</option>
                <option>Truck Driver</option>
                <option>Web Developer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>In</div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter State" name="">
        <div>
            <div>Search by Game</div>   
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name A Game" name="">
        </div>
    <div>   
        {{Form::submit('Find A Game', array('class' => 'btn')) }}
    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
  <!--  </form> -->
```

Comment: Great comments, thank you. If I may follow up. I'm does that mean I don't need the handle index post method I had there? Also: How do I know what name to give my view form input? Thanks

Comment: Your form will handle `POST` methods? In your code, it's using `GET`. As for your inputs name, it's similar to plain PHP. You have an `<input type="text" name="price"`, in your PHP code, you access it with `Input::get('price')`.

Comment: If you are only just starting with Laravel, i suggest you join us at: https://larachat.slack.com , the chat room for laravel devs

Comment: Hah, thanks I am! I'll be up all night working away at this. I'm just trying to get a query working to show me one result.

Comment: Getting straight into the bath is fine. However, i highly recommend you start with tutorials: http://daylerees.com/codebright
It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Actually thats ironic you post that because I literally spent the past few months reading that whole book and subscribed to Jeffrey Way's Laracasts. The problem is their tutorial only shows how to create a CRUD with a form to Edit and Delete. I need to search a DB. This is where the confusion is coming in. I'm trying to create equivalent pages for a searching and i'm getting stuck at the routing. In fact I cant find indepth tutorial anywhere.

Comment: There are no tutorials about this since, it's all about using your combined knowledge to create the search results. You'll need to know about routes, views, controllers and eloquent. Just hit me with the questions as you go. I'm at the slack chat room most of the time.